# Android - simple Thread loop doesn't work

Tags: android, multithreading

I want a thread loop that changes String each time. (e.g. d -> dd -> ddd -> dddd...) I expected it to update the view as well as the Thread is excuted , but the screen stops at the first run() excution (which is "dd"). What is wrong? Thanks!

```
package com.example.name.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread t1 = new thread();
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private class thread extends Thread {

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {

            String text = "d";
            while (true) {
                try {
                    text += "d";
                    textView.setText(text);
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The UI elements has to be updated in the UI thread. Either use handler to post or `runOnUiThread` to update the `TextView`. Also use the CamelCase for Class name as per the naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread t1 = new thread();
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private class thread extends Thread {

        String text = "d";

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(text);
                        }
                    });
                    sleep(5000);
                    text += "d";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="digitdemo.com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Count"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Press"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: your welcome @ysd and thank you to mark as a right answer. happy to help you. keep coding.

Answer (score 1):

All the ui elements are handled on main thread. Hence to update any ui element you must do it from the main thread (UI Thread). you can use `runOnUiThread` to switch to UI thread:

```
TextView textView;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread t1 = new thread();
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }

 private class thread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {

            String text = "d";
            while (true) {
                try {
                    text += "d";
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(text);
                        }
                    });

                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this..it will give same output as you want.**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                thread t1 = new thread();
                t1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private class thread extends Thread {

        String text = "d";

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(text);
                        }
                    });
                    sleep(5000);
                    text += "d";
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the thread class for simple task of incrementing and updating UI use handler.Handler runs in the same main thread with different  execution environment.

create a simple handler and update main thread if you want.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
String text = "d";

Runnable runnable=null;
Handler newHandler=null;

private void runTask() {
    newHandler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //update UI
                text += "d";
                textView.setText(text);
                newHandler.post(runnable);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    newHandler.post(runnable);
   }
}
```

and to stop the handler use

```
newHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```